# Sharepoint Custom Field default template

Tags: sharepoint

I want to develop a custom lookup field for sharepoint.

I created a class as the following

```
public class CustomLookupControl:BaseFieldControl
```

and overided this method

```
protected override string DefaultTemplateName
        {
            get
            {
                return base.DefaultTemplateName;                    
            }
        }
```

but when I edit an item I find that the place of the field is empty.

my question is that I don't want to implement a custom rendering template for the field, I want to use the default template of the lookup field

how can this be achieved.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are inheriting `BaseFieldControl`, not `LookupField`, the `base.DefaultTemplateName` will not render a lookup like you want. What you need to do is define your own template like this:

```
protected override string DefaultTemplateName
{
  get
  {
    return "MyCustomTemplateName";                   
  }
}
```

Your rendering template, which is an ascs file deployed to the root _controltemplates folder, must have the Id `MyCustomTemplateName`. In your template add the control, in this case `LookupField` and let it figure out what to render. Let it do the work for you and it will get its own DefaultTemplateName. So now your template will look like this:

```
<SharePoint:RenderingTemplate ID="MyCustomTemplateName" runat="server">
  <Template>
    <SharePoint:LookupField runat="server" />
    // Other custom stuff you want to add
  </Template>
</SharePoint:RenderingTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll probably want to inherit from the [Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.LookupField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.lookupfield.aspx) class, which is a lookup-specific descendant of the BaseFieldControl.